# Invertible upper triangular matrices are diagonalizable.

Tags: matrices

Is this 'result' true? I think it is so as we can choose the first column as pivot point and make all the entries of the first row zero (this can be done as all the diagonal entries are non zero to keep the determinant non zero). And then doing this repeatedly, we can make the whole matrix, a diagonal one. Also suggest an elegant proof if the 'result' is true.

Comment: No, it's false: $\left(\matrix{1&1\\ 0&1}\right)$ is not diagonalizable. Diagonalization doesn't involve pivots.

Comment: Thanks, can you point out the mistake in my argument?

Comment: "make all the entries of the first row zero" how?

Comment: By row and column operations that preserve the similarity class of the matrix.

Comment: No, they don't. Only if you do a row column and simultaneously do the corresponding inverse column operation.